# Does this provide automatic memory managment as well as control of memory? shared_ptr< unique_ptr< Data > >?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I've been working on games and a lot of the time I want to use a smart pointer but I want it to be like a shared pointer, where it deletes the memory automatically when the reference count reaches 0, as well as being able to force it to free when I want it to, and all the shared_ptr's should know that the object has been freed.

Does this do that?

```
class Data
    {
    //stuff
    };

shared_ptr< unique_ptr< Data > > mBestOfBothWorlds( new unique_ptr<Data>( new Data() ) );
```

What are the performance implications of this?  Would it be prohibitively slow?  Would it work correctly?

Seems like not only do you get automatic memory management but also manual management, and the ability to swap out the Data with other Data and everyone who has the shared_ptr gets the new Data without any more hassle.

Comment: Note: even with `shared_ptr<Data>` you can swap the *contents* of `Data` for that of another instance.

Comment: When you do that, isn't it only for that shared_ptr or it is for all of them?

Comment: If you do `swap(ptr, otherptr)` then you swap the pointers, but if you do `swap(*ptr, *otherptr)` then you swap the pointees and thus all pointers to the same pointee see the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unique_ptr`is a pretty thin wrapper so I don't understand why did you decide it would be prohibitively slow. While I don't see any technical problems with your approach I think you violate the very purpose of the smart pointers. Smart pointers are all about ownership and only they should manage ownership you should not touch it. In my opinion with such approach you will someday end up with some nasty bug.